# How can I use PID to precisely control a Thermoelectric Cooler (TEC) while also supplying 24V?

Tags: power-supply, pid-controller, peltier

I need to use a TEC to stabilize the temperature of an instrument. My thought is to have a thermistor provide live temperature data to a PID controller which would stabilize the TEC to a set temperature. The only problem is that the TEC(or other similar ones) that I want to use requires 24V and ~2.5A (60W) to run properly. [This is the TEC I would like to use.](https://www.lairdthermal.com/products/thermoelectric-cooler-assemblies/peltier-liquid-series/LA-075-24-02)

[This is the ideal TEC driver (Laird TC-XX-PR-59) and PID controller](https://www.lairdthermal.com/products/product-temperature-controllers/tc-xx-pr-59-temperature-controller) because it can supply 24V and up to 15A. However, they are out of stock everywhere, and I cannot find an equivalent. We have on hand [a bunch of these Arroyo 5240 TEC Controllers](https://www.arroyoinstruments.com/products/5240). Ideally, we would be able to these Arroyo units since they are "plug and play" and won't require anything other than a wall outlet. However, they only go up to 7V and 4A (28W). They would be delivering under half of the recommended power to the TECs, and I am not sure if that would be enough cooling capacity to stabilize our instruments.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to provide these TECs with 24V, but also have some sort of PID control to stabilize the temperature? Also, if I were to find a solution similar to the TC-XX-PR-59, what is the process of connecting it to power from the wall?

I have spent a lot of time researching and thinking about this, but I need some help. I apologize for any easy mistakes and misunderstandings that I am making. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: how to use PID and how to supply power questions cannot be answered with one answer ... please ask the questions separately

Comment: Usually the answer would be "use a regular PID controller and SSR", but TECs are a special case, because there are many operating conditions where they will cool *less* with greater power input, leading to thermal runaway.

Comment: I would keep looking for a TEC controller.

Comment: It looks like you're looking for boxes that you can assemble, here, not like you're planning on designing a board -- is that correct?

Comment: @TimWescott Yes, that is correct. I am looking for a commercial solution that will be able to handle the PID, and deliver enough power to the PID controllers. 

That, or have some sort of PID controller that is able to control some sort of other power delivery system. I'm not quite sure. 

Basically, I need to have a 24V ~3A supply to power the TECs, and I also need to be able to control them somehow. I am looking for ideas on how to accomplish this.

I am not too familiar with circuit design, so I don't think I could design something capable of this on my first try.